# Identificar variables distorsionantes en R con un Boxplot

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy en clase de R realizando detección de outliers, y tras realizar un boxplot con todas mis variables númericas, tengo que identificar "variables distorsionantes", excluirlas y volver a repetir el boxplot.

Tengo dudas sobre lo de "distorsionantes", y mi razonamiento es que la mayoría de mis variables tienen rangos númericos muy bajos, pero sin embargo tengo dos variables con rangos altísimos en comparación, y al visualizar un boxplot conjunto de todas las variables, la escala se distorsiona por estas dos variables.

Les dejo mi boxplot, a ver qué les parece:

[image: Boxplot de todas las variables númericas]

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido R. C a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Tu pregunta es más para una opinión que para una respuesta concreta, por lo que eventualmente terminará cerrada. Lo que puedo decirte, es que las medianas de todas las variables son muy similares salvo en la ante última variable a derecha. Esa variable es la mejor candidata para quitar de la gráfica.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Patricio!